# My computer looks yellowish in certain places when the screen is dark, and the places change when I move my screen

Tags: display, colors

I restarted my computer and realized that the off-black of the background actually looked slightly yellow in places. I thought it was the light, but I don't think it was. It changes when I change the screen positioning. I just got this computer (Acer Nitro 5) and I'm very worried. Have I damaged the screen somehow? I'm almost certain that this is the case. The yellow is always in the edges. Will this get worse? And finally, did my Acer Nitro 5 come with a warranty to get this fixed?

It just looks slightly yellower near the edges in places.

Comment: I just got this computer     ....  Ask for warranty repair or replacement. Don't wait.

Comment: An LCD panel can leak a small amount of light at very edges. Compare the display with another LCD to see if it's much worse. However, as @John states, return it if you have issues.

Comment: It looks pretty bad. It also changes when I change the screen angle. I will probably return it.